# Semantic UI ui form segment has no height in sidebar

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I have a button that slides out a vertical sidebar. Inside the sidebar I want to have a short form for the user to enter in search queries.

`#search-sidebar` is the correct height.
`.ui.form.segment` has a height of only 4px.

I'm at a loss to what's going on...

```
<div id="search-sidebar" class="overlay ui very wide red vertical demo sidebar menu">
  <div class="ui form segment">
    <div class="two fields">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Number of Bedrooms</label>
        <input type="number" name="bedrooms">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Number of Bathrooms</label>
        <input type="number" name="bathrooms">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three fields">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Interior Size</label>
        <div class="ui icon input">
          <input type="number" name="interiorSize">
          <i class="inverted icon">m<sup>2</sup></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Exterior Size</label>
        <div class="ui icon input">
          <input type="number" name="exteriorSize">
          <i class="inverted icon">m<sup>2</sup></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Price</label>
        <div class="ui icon input">
          <i class="inverted yen icon"></i>
          <input type="number" name="price">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You have to add `class="item"` around the `.ui.form.segment`. I'm not sure why you have to do it though.

```
<div id="search-sidebar" class="overlay ui very wide red vertical demo sidebar menu">
<div class="item">
  <div class="ui form segment">
    <div class="two fields">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Number of Bedrooms</label>
        <input type="number" name="bedrooms">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Number of Bathrooms</label>
        <input type="number" name="bathrooms">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three fields">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Interior Size</label>
        <div class="ui icon input">
          <input type="number" name="interiorSize">
          <i class="inverted icon">m<sup>2</sup></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Exterior Size</label>
        <div class="ui icon input">
          <input type="number" name="exteriorSize">
          <i class="inverted icon">m<sup>2</sup></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Price</label>
        <div class="ui icon input">
          <i class="inverted yen icon"></i>
          <input type="number" name="price">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```